# DRF: How to pass Foreign key Select options to show in the forms

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have the following

```
class Pet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    breed = models.ForeignKey(
        "Breed",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
```

Now i Have the serializer as:

```
class PetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Pet
        fields = "__all__
```

and viewset

```
class PetViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Pet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PetSerializer
```

Now i am creating a simple form with name and select for breed

```
<form>
  <label for="name">Name</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br>
  <label for="breeds">Choose a car:</label>
  <select name="breeds" id="breeds">
    <option value="1">Breed1</option>
    <option value="2">Breed2</option>
    <option value="3">Breed3</option>
    <option value="4">Breed4</option>
    ...
  </select>
</form>
```

Till now I was using Django forms. Which populate select fields automatically.

Since with DRF there is no such thing.

I have to write the form manually. So how to populate the select options

I am fine with ajax or reacts also.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear which technology you are using for the frontend. If you are using django template engine, you just need to override the `get_context_data` method in the view that's rendering this template (or add it to the context dictionary passed to the render() method if you are not using class-based views), to include breeds objects.

For example:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['breeds'] = Breeds.objects.all()  # or customize the queryset
    return context
```

Otherwise, if you are using a js framework like react or vue you have to do a request from your frontend to the breeds endpoint in order to retrieve a list of them (so you need a view exposing that resource). Than use a for loop inside the select tag iterating through the breeds object so you can use the property you need to populate the value attribute of the option tag.
Here an example using vue, assuming that you stored the response.json() a variable named breeds.

```
<form>
  <label for="name">Name</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br>
  <label for="breeds">Choose a car:</label>
  <select name="breeds" id="breeds">
    <option 
      v-for="breed in breeds"
      :key="breed.id"
      :value="breed.id"
    >{{ breed.name }}</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Note that I'm using breed.id as the value option tags, since ModelSerializer use pk by default to represent relationships.